# Extract specific substring from string

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a string like this :

```
String myExample = "Ticket Order 3748594 / 45 : blablabla"
```

I want to extract the substring "3748594" from it, how can I do that?

PS : My string could also be something like : "WARNING : Ticket Order 3748594 / 45 : blablabla", the "Ticket Order /number/" has no predefined position.

Comment: Do you mean replace  "3748594" with blank? or get the number that is between `Order` and `/` ?

Comment: regex is common in this situation. though if you know the positions of the numbers you can use `String#subString`

Comment: You can simply use `myExample.substring(13, 20);`, as you haven't provided any condition to extract.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I want to get the number and put it into another.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava Yes I can do that for this example but I prefer to referer to the "Ticket Order" string and get the numbers that a directly after.

Comment: `Integer ticket = Integer.parseInt(myExample.replaceFirst("Ticket Order\\s+(\\d+).*", "$1"));`

Comment: Please read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this situation like below :

```
    String line = "Ticket Order 3748594 / 45 : blablabla";
    String pattern = "[0-9]{5,}"; //this means at least 5 length of digits

    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

    if (m.find( )) {
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
    }else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
```

Also if your pattern is always like "Ticket Order [digits]" you can use your regex pattern as

```
    String pattern = "Ticket Order [0-9]{5,}";
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want.

You can use the simple pattern `\d+`

So:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myExample);
if(m.matches()) // or m.find()
{
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // output is 3748594
    // m.group(1) is 45
}
```

Comment: escape the backslash in regex: `Pattern.compile("\\d+");`